# startVPNTunnel not throws errors

Tags: ios, ios9, vpn, networkextension

I'm calling startVPNTunnel() and then in the PacketTunnelProvider class, I execute the completionBlock with an error.
The call to startVPNTunnel() is inside a try-catch block, but it's seems that there is nothing to catch.
I just want to alert the user if the connection succeeded or not.
Anyone else was able to catch those errors?

The relevant code is very simple:

```
do {
       try vpnManager!.connection.startVPNTunnel()
   }
catch {
       NSLog("roee: Failed to start vpn: \(error)")
}
```

And inside PacketTunnelProvider:

```
 let error = NSError(domain: NEVPNErrorDomain, code: NEVPNError.ConfigurationInvalid.rawValue, userInfo: nil)
            PacketTunnelProvider.pendingStartCompletionHandler!(error)
            PacketTunnelProvider.pendingStartCompletionHandler = nil
```

Comment: Can you put some code that enable us reproduce the error?

Comment: I can catch the error with: `} catch let error as NSError {`

Comment: Hi, perhaps did you managed to trigger the extension to raise ? can you share your solution principles ? thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `startVPNTunnel` talks to OS and let it knows that VPN needs to be started.

OS will do couple of checks around VPN configuration and will immediately return positive result (if configuration is fine) or error (if something is wrong). And if an error is returned then this API will throw.

However, your Network extension will be started *after* `startVPNTunnel` returned.

So you can't communicate like that.

You can register for `NSNotification.Name.NEVPNStatusDidChange` to see VPN status changes.

Comment: Yep, already discovered that (and forgot this question, 1 year ago..) but you are right.

Comment: Hi can you tell me please, Why I am not able to establish the connection on first request but it is working after first requests.

Comment: But how would that give me access to the error? When the status changes to not connected because of an error, how would the main application know because of which error the tunnel establishment failed?

Comment: @Mecki did you find solution?

Comment: @DenAndreychuk Not really. I worked around it by moving the app and the tunnel provider to the same app group, giving them both access to a shared app group container. If the tunnel provider fails with an error, it writes that error to the container before going into error state. If the main app notices the provider went into error state, it will look into that container to find the error. You could also use IPC to transfer the error to the main application but the file based approach also works correctly if the main application isn't even running when the error happens.

Comment: @Mecki, I also encountered the same error scenario. I've got an app and a network extension which doesn't goes up upon calling `startVPNTunnel`. I've followed you instruction and put the network extension under my app in sub folder `Contents/Library/SystemExtensions` and gave both the app and the extension the same identifier. However, as said , the extension failed to be loaded... Perhaps you can help figure out where did i go wrong in my deployment ? thanks !